# How to resize components on GWT?

Tags: java, gxt

I need to resize ContentPanel, which is in another ContentPanel, which is in etc. on the browser resize:

```
ContentPanel cpReport = new ContentPanel();          
cpReport.setHeaderVisible(false);        
cpReport.addListener(Events.Resize, new Listener<BaseEvent> () {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
        //What TODO?     
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this GXT or old version of GWT? Did you come across GWT's - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Resize

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by this way, but you can advize me better things:

```
cpReport.addListener(Events.Resize, new Listener<BaseEvent> () {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
        cpReport.setAutoWidth(true);
        cpReport.setAutoHeight(true);
        }
    });
```

Thank for everybody